# how to add a new sheet and use it to paste tables in vba

Tags: excel, vba

i want a macro to add a new sheet and use it to paste some tables, but i when i run the macro again i wanna use the same newly created sheet and not to add a new sheet everytime i run the macro. Can u help me?

I am using the code that folows:

```
Sub cria_relatorio()

Dim newS As Worksheet, currentS As Worksheet
Dim aba_anterior As Worksheet



lugarAnterior = Selection.Address


Set pos = ActiveSheet
Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook
Set currentS = currentWB.Sheets("fim")
currentS.Range("PRODUTOS").Select 'table that i wanna copy and paste(it changes the values)

Selection.Copy


Sheets("tabelas_por_produto").Activate
  
   ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
       Range("A1").Activate

        
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    
ElseIf Range("a1000").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) = "" Then
   Range("a1000").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select

Else
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
End If

ActiveCell.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, _
    Transpose:=False


ActiveCell.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, _
    Transpose:=False

ActiveCell.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, _
    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, _
    Transpose:=False
    
     Rows("1:200").AutoFit


    
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify for what circumstances you want to add a new sheet and when not to? For example, if the a new sheet is created and the name is "data" then check if sheet "data" exists. If it doesn't exist, add a new sheet otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Versions of a Range One Below the Other

- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. Module1).
- Carefully adjust the **const**ants and the **workbook** if necessary.
- It is assumed that `PRODUTO` is a defined
  [name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name) of
  a range, with workbook scope.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub cria_relatorio()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcName As String = "fim"
    Const tgtName As String = "tabelas_por_produto"
    Const rngName As String = "PRODUTOS"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A1"
    Const tgtOffset As Long = 2
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim src As Range: Set src = wb.Names(rngName).RefersToRange
    
    ' Define Target worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName): GoSub NoWorksheet
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Define Target Cell.
    Dim tgt As Range
    Set tgt = ws.Columns(ws.Range(tgtFirst).Column) _
                .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If tgt Is Nothing Then Set tgt = ws.Range(tgtFirst)
    If tgt.Row < ws.Range(tgtFirst).Row Then Set tgt = ws.Range(tgtFirst)
    Set tgt = tgt.Offset(tgtOffset)
    
    ' Do copy/paste.
    src.Copy
    With tgt.Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Rows.AutoFit
    End With
    
    Exit Sub

NoWorksheet:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        wb.Worksheets.Add
        Set ws = ActiveSheet: ws.Name = tgtName
    End If
    Return

End Sub
```